# Vue.js tag as invalid HTML

Tags: javascript, html, intellij-idea, vue.js, vuejs2

My Vue variable is defined as a invalid HTML tag. How do i prevent this and how can i use my Vue.js variables?

I get this error: attribute v-bind is not allowed here, The inspection highlight unknown HTML tag attributes as invalid, and lets mark such attributes as custom to avoid highlighting them as invalid

I use Intellij

```
<script  src="../../static/js/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app-2">
<span v-bind:title="message">
Hover your mouse over me for a few seconds
to see my dynamically bound title!
</span>
</div>

<script>
var app2 = new Vue({
    el: '#app-2',
    data: {
        message: 'You loaded this page on ' + new Date().toLocaleString()
    }
})
</script>
```

Comment: The error message seems to be telling you exactly what to do about it: *"...mark such attributes as custom to avoid highilghting them as invalid."* (but it's hard to tell, because you didn't mark up the error message correctly, so it's hard to tell what part is error message vs. your own text).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code works (see snippet). Just be sure Vue is well defined.

```js
var app2 = new Vue({
    el: '#app-2',
    data: {
        message: 'You loaded this page on ' + new Date().toLocaleString()
    }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app-2">
  <span v-bind:title="message">
      Hover your mouse over me for a few seconds to see my dynamically bound title!
  </span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a `data-` prefix before it to make it a valid html attribute.

```
<span data-v-bind:title="message">
```

Comment: then i get the error: Namespace data-v-bind is not bound, this inspection checks for unbound namespaces prefixes in xml

Comment: Just declare the namespace then.

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be the colon. You can write like this instead:

```
<span v-bind="{title: message}">
```

That will work in IntelliJ.

Answer (score 0):

What helped me with the error was changing 
    `<html>` to `<!DOCTYPE html>`